# SSH-FS to remote server on another SSH remote server

Tags: bash, ssh, visual-studio-code, sshfs

So, there exists the first SSH server, called A for simplicity, and the files and workspace I want to get to are on another SSH server, called B. Problem is, B is only accessible by SSH'ing to it from A. 
So if I were to do this normally, I'd ssh into A, and from there ssh into B, or just `ssh -t A "ssh B"` which becomes mildly inefficient, if I were  to code in B using vim.

So I don't know exactly how to sshfs B onto my local machine, but I can sshfs A. Sshfs'ing B onto A isn't possible, as A doesn't have it installed. Is there a way to sshfs B?

A and B are both Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and my computer is a Macbook Pro 2015.
I've tried the SSH-FS extension with VSCode. It only connects to A.

I also tried the Remote-SSH extension, and again, only gets as far as A. I even used -t for the connection command, but it doesn't seem to make any changes to the Remote-SSH config file.

I also tried ssh-fs while tunneled into A. No results there either.

Sorry for the trouble. This is a really niche problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use .ssh/config to have the ability to connect to `B` in on command from your Macbook Pro .

a example :

```
Host serverb.via.servera
    HostKeyAlias            serverb
    User                    account_on_b
    ProxyCommand            ssh account_on_a@servera  -W serverb:22
```

before using sshfs , you must test the setting by running :

```
ssh  serverb.via.servera
```

and if you have your shell , so you can run

```
sshfs serverb.via.servera:/yourdir/ /tmp/localdir/
```

remarks:

- `serverb.via.servera` is a arbritrary string , that you must use instead of the host
- `account_on_a`   and `account_on_b`  must be replace by the login you use on each servers

Comment: How would `serverb.via.servera` work? Something like `ssh user@domainb.com.via.user@domaina.com` ?

Comment: Use `ProxyJump` option, instead of `ProxyCommand` if your openssh version supports it. It is simpler to understand and works the same way.